# Generate presigned url for versions in S3 with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

So I'm struggling to find information on a way to generate a presigned url for each version of a file in S3. I'm able to grab all the versions, but when calling generate_presigned_url() I do not have a Key to pass from the version object. Is there any way to do this?  I'm hoping to not need to download each version, but if that's the only way to do it that's fine.

Here is my current snippet:

```
for version in versions:
    object = version.get()
    url = s3Client.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='get_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': bucket,
            'Key': object.get('VersionID') #Not sure what value to put here?
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did some more digging on this one. It looks like it IS possible to get a presigned URL to an older version of a file using the 'VersionId' parameter. This parameter was not mentioned as supported for the generate_presigned_url call, but I tried it out anyways and it worked.

```
for version in versions:
    object = version.get()
    url = s3Client.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='get_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': bucket,
            'Key': key,
            'VersionId': object.get('VersionId')
        }
    )
```