# How to create Pre-signed URL for specific version of file in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

How to create a Pre-signed URL for the specific version of a file in AWS S3?

If the bucket is enabled for file versioning and file has more than one version and wants to create presigned url for speific version of file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate presigned url for versions in S3 with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466415/generate-presigned-url-for-versions-in-s3-with-boto3)

Answer (score 0):

Just need to pass the `version_id` along with key to create pre-signed url for the specific version of the file.

Python Example:

```
def get_pre_signed_url(bucket, file_name):
    try:
        response = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get("aws_access_key_id"), aws_secret_access_key=os
                                .environ.get("aws_secret_access_key"), region_name=os.environ.get("region_name"))\
            .generate_presigned_post(Bucket=bucket, Key=os.environ.get('folder_location') + file_name,
                                     ExpiresIn=300)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None
    return response
```

Filename is `{fileName}?versionId={versionId}`

Check this [repo](https://github.com/m-thirumal/s3-pre-signed-url), for more information

Comment: Your code sample doesn't include the `version_id`, and it's for a POST, rather than a GET operation.